# Do i have to use f:param?

Tags: jsf

I would like to use f:setPropertyActionListener because it is tidy.

But i must pass parameter to a page from another page.

Code in first.xhtml:

```
<h:button outcome="second.jsf" >
<f:setPropertyActionListener ...>
</h:button>
```

i want user to go second.jsf with parameters in f:setPropertyActionListener. but eclipse says i cannot use h:button with f:setPropertyActionListener .

if i want to write

```
<h:commandButton action="secondController.someaction" >
<f:setPropertyActionListener ...>
</h:commandButton>
```

then i must redirect page in "someaction" but secondController is view scoped and i lose parameter again.

Hope i could tell my problem. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `<f:param>`. The `<h:button>` sends a GET request, not a POST request.